# Use User username as url in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django-rest-framework

> I am trying to use the username of a user for the URL so that I can
>   access user details at:
>
> > http://localhost:8000/api/users/usernamegoeshere

in my urls.py I have

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import UserViewSet
from django.conf.urls import url
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

urlpatterns = [
    path("users/", UserListView.as_view(), name="all-users"),
    path("users/<slug>/", UserViewSet),

]
```

views.py

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from .serializers import UserSerializer
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    slug_field = 'username'
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_framework.relations import HyperlinkedIdentityField
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
         model = User
         fields = ('url', 'username', 'email', 'id')
         slug_field = 'username'
```

> Whenever I try to go to the individual users page I get this
>   error:  TypeError at /api/users/usernamegoeshere/
>   **init**() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can everything in a simple ViewSet (in fact, the model viewset has all 4 actions - list, create, update, delete).  All you need to set is the [`lookup_field`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#attributes) property on the viewset.

When using a ViewSet you should also use a Router.  Generally stick to the [SimpleRouter](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#simplerouter).  Read up on the other one, but its rarely what you want.

```
class UserViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    lookup_field = "username"

    def get_queryset(self):
        return User.objects.all()


user_router = SimpleRouter()
user_router.register("users", UserViewSet, basename="users")

urlpatterns = [
    # other url patterns you have
]
urlppatterns += user_router.urls
```

You can run `./manage.py show_urls` to see the routes that were created.  You should see something like `../users/<username>/` in there.

Note: While you can use a `ViewSet` directly when setting up the urls, you generally shouldn't.  The router handles creating and mapping the methods, and giving them appropriate names so they can be reversed predictably.  It also handles mapping the `@action` methods you can add to a ViewSet.

If you have to do it manually then you should probably be using an `ApiView` instead, one for each path.

Answer (score 0):

Change `path("users/<slug>/", UserViewSet),`

to
`path("users/<slug>/", UserViewSet.as_view()),`